# For elliptic curves, how to express the condition at which the vertical tangent line L, to curve E, at point P is at infinity point?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

So I'm writing an essay for my school program. I'm trying to convey the two cases at which P + Q = (a point at infinity). I've written the following for case 1:

(1) P != Q and x<sub>p</sub> = x<sub>q</sub> then P + Q = (point at infinity)

(2) This is the case that I don't know how to convey best. I've seen one maths paper say that in this case when P is a vertical tangent to the elliptic curve E and doesn't intersect any other points, then you can say P = Q and x<sub>p</sub> = 0 then P + Q or P + P = (point at infinity). But what confuses me is that, doesn't the condition of x<sub>p</sub>, just cover the case in which the vertical tangent to E is at x-coordinate zero, but doesn't necessarily cover for when the vertical tangent to E is at other x coordinates, or am I mistaken?

(3)In another paper I read that they said y<sub>p</sub> = y<sub>p</sub> = 0 then P + P = (point at infinity) and that left me even more confused. Because that one I don't agree with at all.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: $y_P = 0$ is the correct condition! Your curve has equation $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$. The vertical tangents are the points where $dx/dy = 0$. You have $2ydy/dx = 3x^2 + a$, so $dx/dy = 2y/(3x^2 + a)$.

Comment: The paper you refer to in item (3) undoubtedly constrains itself to deal with elliptic curves in the short Weierstrass form of $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, when vertical tangents occur at exactly the points with $y=0$.

Comment: Your confusion in item (2) may be related to not understanding the nature of the point at infinity. To calibrate your intuition: Are you ok with the idea that **every** vertical line goes through **the same** point at infinity? If not, you may need to learn about the projective plane and homogeneous coordinates. In the case of elliptic curves we get away with using a single point at infinity, but in the projective plane there is a separate point at infinity to each family of parallel lines. Only one of those points lies on the elliptic curve (when in standard form) though.